# Randomly interchange columns of a matrix: Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose

```
A = [1 2 3 5 7 9
     6 5 0 3 2 3]
```

I want to randomize the position of the matrix column position; to give `B` like so:

```
B = [3 9 1 7 2 5
     0 3 6 2 5 3]
```

How can I do this Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
B = A(randperm(length(A)))
```

Consult the documentation for explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) function to generate a random permutation of column indices (from 1 to the number of columns in `A`), which you can then index `A` with:

```
B = A(:, randperm(size(A, 2)));
```

Comment: Just beat me to this by 20 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Now that code is formatted properly, it's clear the OP wants column preservation, although [`randperm`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) is still the easiest option as given by HPM's answer.

```
idx = randperm(size(A,2)); % Create list of integers 1:n, in random order, 
                           % where n = num of columns

B = A(:, idx);             % Shuffles columns about, on all rows, to indixes in idx
```

Comment: A few "related" links deep, hence the old post, and an itch to correct unformatted code! Didn't realise until I went to edit that it was actually a 2D matrix.